# working with reverse arrays

Tags: java, arrays, char, reverse

I'm working on a programming lab for school and don't quite understand the question. Does anyone understand what exactly is being asked? I do not need help writing the code; just understanding what is being asked. My teacher is not responding to emails.

"Write a method that returns an array composed of all the elements in the array of chars in reversed order. Submit screeshots. Screenshots should involve the name of the beginning of the array, show all values before the array is reversed, and values in the new array after is created."

Comment: Sounds like you're just flipping the order. Input of `['a', 'b', 'c']` would have output of `['c', 'b', 'a']`

Comment: Take a `char[]`, create a new `char[]` and populate it with the original - reversed.

Comment: `Screenshots should involve the name of the beginning of the array`  I'm not sure what exactly this means.  The rest is what everyone else has posted.  Also, I'm glad you clarified you wanted help just understanding what the requirements meant (and not asking us to write the code for you).  :)

Comment: i guess she meant the variable name ? cuz that name points to the first char in the array ("the name of the beginning of the array"), thats how teachers explain stuff :P

Answer (score 1):

Given the input `{'H','e','l','l','o'}`
your output should be `{'o','l','l','e','H'}`

Answer (score 0):

The professor is just asking for the `reverse` of the character array input.

Input: Character array:

```
 {'s','o','m','e','t','h','i','n','g'}
```

Output: Reverse Character array:

```
 {'g','n','i','h','t','e','m','o','s'}
```